# Why `Integrate[-2 E^x - E^x x^2 Cos[x] - x^2 Sin[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` is evaluated to `7/2`? Is it a bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

I have noticed that integral `Integrate[-2 E^x + 2 E^x Cos[x] - E^x x^2 Cos[x] + 2 E^x x Sin[x] - x^2 Sin[x] + E^x x^2 Sin[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` evaluates to `2` and by removing terms one by one, arrived to `Integrate[-2 E^x - E^x x^2 Cos[x] - x^2 Sin[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` which is evaluated to `7/2`.

I think, this is entirely wrong: the both integrals are divergent, and morover, they are infinitely negative due to the term `-2 E^x`. While the other terms change their signs and can be integrated using an averaging method (Cesaro, Abel), the first term simply monotonously grows. Thus, the integrals cannot be interpreted even as Laplace transforms (the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}_t[e^t](x)$ is not defined at $x=0$ according to the Laplace transform tables).

Comment: unrelated question: did you ask today a question about Laplace transform and I left you a comment? Because I cannot find it.

Comment: I think you are correct - I get the same answers in V12.3.  You should report it as a bug.

Comment: I disagree only that the integral is $-\infty$; it has an infinite oscillation (between $\pm\infty$), the dominant terms being `2 E^x x^2 (Cos[x] + Sin[x])`.

Comment: @bmf i have deleted it because it was my mistake. Everything was correct there. The question is here, you can see my last comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265760/why-laplacetransformevaluate2-et-1-et-t-x-x-0-gives-1?noredirect=1#comment662417_265760

Comment: @MichaelE2 the first term does not oscillate. The others can be summed up to finite values using averaging methods.

Comment: @Anixx thanks for letting me know. The page is broken, I just wanted to check if the matter was resolved :) thanks again

Comment: @MichaelE2 is correct about the oscillation.  Consider plotting "on a log scale" in the following manner:  `f = -2 E^x + 2 E^x Cos[x] - E^x x^2 Cos[x] + 2 E^x x Sin[x] - x^2 Sin[x] + E^x x^2 Sin[x]; Plot[Log[Abs[f]]*Sign[f], {x, 0, 50}]`.

Comment: @JimB as I said, the first term does not oscillate, it is infinitely nehative. The oscillating terms can be summed up by averaging methods (Cesaro, Abel) or interpreted as Laplace transform. The first term goes to negative infinity.

Comment: (1) `Integrate` does not compute the Cesaro or Abel "sum", so such values seem irrelevant to what to expect from `Integrate`. (2) The integral is neither Cesaro $(C,1)$ nor Abel summable, though Gauss summability tames the oscillatory component, if Mathematica gave me the correct answer.

Comment: @Michael E2 I think the oscillatory terms could be Cesaro (higher order) or Abel summable. Integrate definitely should return it as is because it is divergent.

Comment: Mathematica  probably uses **Regularization**, because:`Limit[Integrate[
   Exp[-s x]*(-2 E^x + 2 E^x Cos[x] - E^x x^2 Cos[x] + 
      2 E^x x Sin[x] - x^2 Sin[x] + E^x x^2 Sin[x]), {x, 0, Infinity},
    Assumptions -> s > 0][[1]], s -> 0]` gives : `2` .

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Yes, it is the regularized value. But the integral of the very first term `Integrate[-2 E^x {x, 0, Infinity}]` already has the regularized value 2. But if you try to evaluate it, Mathematica would fail. For my purposes I would be OK with the regularization of the oscillatory terms, but not the infinite term.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk In the Abel regularization, the result of `Integrate` assumes `Exp[x - s x]` approaches zero as `x -> Infinity`, which is why we get a conditional result from `Integrate` (`s > 1`) and how the oscillatory terms vanish. I didn't think it was permitted to ignore that condition, which is why I said the integral wasn't Abel summable. If it is permitted, then this is an area of math I'm not familiar with, and I should probably not say anything further about it. Regularizing with `Exp[-s^2 x^2]` yields $-\infty$ as the OP seeks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make progress is to use [`Rubi`](https://rulebasedintegration.org/)

```
Get["Rubi`"]

$Version
$RubiVersion

13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)
"Rubi 4.16.1.0"

Int[-2 E^x + 2 E^x Cos[x] - E^x x^2 Cos[x] + 2 E^x x Sin[x] - 
  x^2 Sin[x] + E^x x^2 Sin[x], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> `Indeterminate`

and also

```
Int[-2 E^x - E^x x^2 Cos[x] - x^2 Sin[x], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> `Indeterminate`

Comment: Rubi has no special engine for definite integration, it just finds the indefinite integral (which is trivial here) and puts in the boundaries.

Comment: @Anixx thanks for the comment. I am aware, and I agree that your post falls in the `bugs` tag for sure. I just pointed this out in case you did not know about `Rubi` and you needed such computations for ongoing projects :-)